# How do I keep a form and its children centred, but have a label stick to the top left corner of my text input?

Tags: html, css

Okay, so maybe I'm not searching properly but I can't seem to find *exactly* what I'm looking for.
I have a form, let's say something like this:

```css
div.some_form {}

div.some_form>span {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

div.some_form>form {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div.some_form>form>input.txtfield {
  padding: 13px;
  width: 25%;
}

.button {
  background-color: #7AB55C;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some_form">
  <form>
    <span class="some_class">Some text</span>
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="txtfield" />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Submit" onclick="doSomething()" />
  </form>
</div>
```

what I want it to do is pretty much keep the inputs centred (which I'm able to do), which is why everything is in a div, I used text-align: center to centre everything, but I want the span element to be stuck to the top left corner of the first input, which I can't seem to do properly.
I mean, I get it, but then once I resize the window, the span shoots off into space (i.e. the text field will expand at a lower rate than the span is, which is great because the text stays centred even with the button attached) and I can't seem to get it to just stick.
(also this seriously isn't homework, I'm just getting into CSS and this is really bothering me..)

any help is obviously very much appreciated!
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `display: block` to your `span` will work. And remove the `<br />`. You have the class specification wrong. The `<span>` isn't a direct child there. So `>` doesn't work:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
div.some_form span.some_class {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 4.5%;
}

div.some_form>form {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div.some_form>form>input.txtfield {
  padding: 13px;
  width: 45%;
}

.button {
  background-color: #7AB55C;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 32px;
}
div.some_form {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="some_form">
  <form>
    <span class="some_class">Some text</span>
    <input type="text" class="txtfield" />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Submit" onclick="doSomething()" />
  </form>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: thank you for your help!! I chose yours as the answer since it works and you explained why :)

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer hope it can help you

```css
       .container{
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   position: absolute; 
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -100px;
   margin-left: -150px;
  }
  .txtfield {
    padding: 13px;
    width: 25%;
  }

  .button {
    background-color: #7AB55C;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 32px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="some_form">
   <form>
    <div class="container">
      <span class="some_class">Some text</span>
      <div class="input_container">
       <input type="text" class="txtfield" />
       <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" onclick="doSomething()" />
      </div>
     </div>
   </form>
 </div>
```